# Oracle: remove first 4 characters from a string

Tags: sql, string, oracle

So I want to remove the first 4 characters from a string in oracle. Those characters can be different every time.
In my case I need to take away the first 4 characters of an IBAN and put them at the end of the string. I got the part of putting them to the end of the string but I can't get the first 4 characters to be removed. Every solution I find on the internet removes specified characters, not characters from a certain position in the string (1 to 4).
I used the code below to get the first 4 characters to the end of the string and wanted to try something similar for removing them at the front but without success.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(iban_nummer, 1, 4) INTO iban_substring FROM dual;
iban_nummer := iban_nummer || iban_substring;
```

Comment: Remove the redundant `number` it's IBAN and **not** IBAN number.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm#OLADM679):

> substring_length ...
>       When you do not specify a value for this argument, then the function returns all characters to the end of string. When you specify
>   a value that is less than 1, the function returns NA.

So `iban_nummer := substr(iban_nummer, 5) || substr(iban_nummer, 1,4)` should work. The first part selects all characters beginning from the 5th, the second character numbers 1..4.

Answer (score 7):

```
update table_name set col_name=substr(col_name,5);
```

Answer (score 1):

try *regexp*, like:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(t.iban_nummer,'(.{4})(.*)','\2\1') FROM t;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Alternative way using regexp :

```
SELECT regexp_replace(t.iban_nummer,'^.{4}(.*)','\2\1') FROM dual;
```