# Remove first characters of string in Oracle Server

Tags: oracle

I have `Table1.column1` in a Oracle Server with text such as `12345678910`.

How can I remove the first six characters of the string? The result should be `78910`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle: remove first 4 characters from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828865/oracle-remove-first-4-characters-from-a-string)

Comment: thanks so much guys.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTR( column1, 7, LENGTH( column1 ) - 6 )
FROM   Table1;
```

or more simply:

```
SELECT SUBSTR( column1, 7 )
FROM   Table1;
```

Answer (score 6):

If you know you want the last five characters of a string you can use a negative value for the second argument to `SUBSTR`, as in:

```
select substr('12345678910', -5) from dual;
```

which produces `'78910'`.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `SUBSTR()` function like

```
select substr(column1, 6, 5)
from Table1;
```