# Azure Data Factory Rename Tables in Pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am doing a bulk copy from one Oracle database to another Oracle database. To do this I am using the bulk copy action that takes and creates a table lookup based on owner.

This works great. However, we are pulling from views with table names appended with 'vw_' and need to remove the prefix. The target Oracle database has the table names listed without the 'vw_'. The flow is simple.

1. We create a lookup of table names
2. We trigger a copy which iterates over each table and copies the data
3. The action sends the copied data to a storage blob
4. Then a copy to consumer action moves the data from the storage account to the target. By that time the query should be correct. We check for the existence of the table and if it is there we truncate the data and reload it.

`IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [@{item().TABLE_SCHEMA}].[@{item().VIEW_NAME}]) TRUNCATE TABLE [@{item().TABLE_SCHEMA}].[@{item().TABLE_NAME}]`

**The problem is I can't rename the table in the pipeline. How do I do this?**

Here is the query that pulls the table names.

```
SELECT OWNER as TABLE_SCHEMA, VIEW_NAME as TABLE_NAME
from SYS.ALL_VIEWS
WHERE  VIEW_NAME LIKE 'VW_RX_%'
```

Here is one of the table names `VW_RX_CASE_WORKLIST`

I want to transform it to RX_CASE_WORKLIST on the Lookup task so we don't have to mess with files in the storage account. [copytask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAkwu.png)

Comment: You can either rename it in your SQL query or you can rename it in your expression.

Comment: To remove first three characters in your Oracle query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889535/remove-first-characters-of-string-in-oracle-server

Comment: ADF substring function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#substring which means replace `@{item().VIEW_NAME}` with something like `@{substring(item().VIEW_NAME,4,100)}`

Answer (score 0):

You remove the first 3 characters (**VW_**) from the view name in the query used in the `lookup` activity.

Below is the result before doing substring.

[image]

**Lookup activity:**

```
SELECT 'dbo' as tb_schema, substring(name, 4, (len(name)-3)) as tb_name
from SYS.ALL_VIEWS
WHERE name LIKE 'VW_%'
```

[image]

You can pass the output of the `lookup` activity to the next activities.

[image]