# Delete first character in whole column in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with deleting first character in a one column of my table and updating my table with new values. I wanna do it in on query (remove first character in string in one column and update table). Anyone can help?

My table:

```sql
ID | column1 | column2
L12| 5       | 10
L14| 6       | 12
```

My desired output:

```sql
ID | column1 | column2
12| 5       | 10
14| 6       | 12
```

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/34889535/1509264 (just in an `UPDATE` statement rather than a `SELECT` statement).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove first characters of string in Oracle Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889535/remove-first-characters-of-string-in-oracle-server)

Comment: What does your question have to do with PL/SQL?

Answer (score 0):

A simple `update` with `substr`:

Before:

```
SQL> select * from your_table;

ID     COLUMN1    COLUMN2
--- ---------- ----------
L12          5         10
L14          6         12
```

Update:

```
SQL> update your_table set
  2    id = substr(id, 2);

2 rows updated.
```

After:

```
SQL> select * from your_table;

ID     COLUMN1    COLUMN2
--- ---------- ----------
12           5         10
14           6         12

SQL>
```

Comment: And you should perhaps also recommend altering the ID column to an integer data type.

Comment: Who, me, @jarlh? I won't. What we see (in this example) is that what you suggest might be true, but that's kind of difficult to do as you can't modify column's datatype if it (the column) isn't empty (yes, there's a way to do it, but ...). On the other hand, maybe there are values that look like 'LA12' which then become 'A12', and that's not an integer.